# SqfLite No such table (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

Maybe this question was already answered but I try to add sqfLite to my project but I get this error:

[image]

In my debug console:

```
no such table: infotable in "SELECT * FROM infotable"
```

This is my code:

```
final String infoTable = 'infotable';
final String columnID = '_id';
final String columnName = 'name';
final String columnCivilStatus = 'civil';
final String columnWorking = 'working';
final String columnJobTitle = 'job';
final String columnWorkingDomain = 'workingdomain';
final String columnMonthlyIncome = 'monthlyincome';

class SqfLite {
  int id;
  int sliderValue;
  int monthChoiceChip;
  String reasonChoiceChip;
  String name;
  String civilStatus;
  int working;
  String jobTitle;
  int workingDomain;
  String monthlyIncome;
  String currency;
  Position latitude;
  Position longitude;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      columnCivilStatus: civilStatus,
      columnJobTitle: jobTitle,
      columnMonthlyIncome: monthlyIncome,
      columnWorkingDomain: workingDomain,
      columnWorking: working,
      columnName: name,
    };
    if (id != null) {
      map[columnID] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  SqfLite();
  SqfLite.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[columnID];
    name = map[columnName];
    civilStatus = map[columnCivilStatus];
    working = map[columnWorking];
    jobTitle = map[columnJobTitle];
    workingDomain = map[columnWorkingDomain];
    monthlyIncome = map[columnMonthlyIncome];
  }
}

class SqfLiteProvider {
  Database db;

  Future open(String path) async {
    db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('''
create table $infoTable ( 
  $columnID integer primary key autoincrement, 
  $columnName text not null,
  $columnCivilStatus text not null,
  $columnWorking integer not null,
  $columnJobTitle text not null,
  $columnWorkingDomain integer not null,
  $columnMonthlyIncome text not null)
''');
    });
  }


  Future<SqfLite> getSqfLite(int id) async {
    List<Map> maps = await db.query(infoTable,
        columns: [
          columnID,
          columnName,
          columnCivilStatus,
          columnWorking,
          columnJobTitle,
          columnWorkingDomain,
          columnMonthlyIncome,
        ],
        where: '$columnID = ?',
        whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      return SqfLite.fromMap(maps.first);
    }
    return null;
  }


  Future close() async => db.close();
}
```

I get the error here:

```
Future<void> openDataBase() async {
    db = await openDatabase('infotable.db');
    records = await db.query('infotable');
    mapRead = records.first;
    ....
  }
```

I've followed the example from the official page of the [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite/versions/1.3.2+4)

I can't use the latest version because of some `pubspec.yaml` conflicts.

I've tried to `flutter clean` and reinstalling the app but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the `open` method inside `SqfLiteProvider`, but you are not using it. Instead, you are calling the same `openDatabase('infotable.db');` method from sqflite package where the `onCreate` callback is not defined - you get an error.

So, instead of calling `db = await openDatabase('infotable.db');` directly, use the `SqfLiteProvider.open()` you have defined.

Comment: Thx for the answer.. I watched some videos and was able to make it work in the end